# Set Image Source of a composer item in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, template, composer-manager

I have QPT file witch has map item and logo item..

here is my code:

```
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(projectqgs))
    bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
    bridge.setCanvasLayers()
    composition = QgsComposition(canvas.mapSettings())
    composition.loadFromTemplate(document, substitution_map)
    map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
    map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
```

but then i need to set Image Source path to my logo item.. Of course i need something like this:

```
logo_item = composition.getComposerItemById('logo')
```

then what should i do? is there anycode similar to this:

```
logo_item.setImageSource(path_to_image)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is :

```
logo_item.setPictureFile(path_to_image)
```